# Does the OS come in the hard drive?

Tags: memory-hardware, os-kernel

This might be a a simple and for some a silly question as well.

If I buy two hard drives and have windows in one and Ubuntu in the other, can I work with both two systems(one at a time).

Example, I wanna edit a photo and I quickly need to go to Adobe Photoshop, so I plug in the Windows harddrive and start editing, then I remember I need to code something real quick so I remove the windows hardrive and plug in the Ubuntu hardrive and start working.

Does it work this way? Is it impractical? Enlighten me.

I could use a VirtualBox, but I want to know if the above is possible.

Comment: You cannot freely switch OS by plugging/unplugging drives, a boot would be needed every time. And you could not share files this way. Virtual machines are more convenient, you can switch instantly and share files between the OSes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that but it is rather awkward. Instead, you can use a [boot loader](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Second-stage_boot_loader) which can load an operating system pass on the execution to it. Many issues and caveats on [multi-booting exist](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting).

In addition, you can use virtualization (for example, [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) is popular) to run say a Linux machine on your host Windows machine.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your first suggestion won't allow running two OSes side by side, you need to pick one at boot time and reboot to pick another. Virtualization doesn't suffer from that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays people don't want their stolen computers to be used by a thief, and they don't want a thief to boot from an external hard drive and somehow manage to access their secrets on an internal drive.

So it is quite possible that an alternative boot drive has to be created on the original machine.